# Dynamically assign rails default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails has parameters to determine which languages are to be used for i18n applications

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.available_locales = [:gr, :en, :ru, :de]
```

An application is a bucket for different owners, who might have different default and available locales.

Assuming there is an Owner class, how can these values be set and thus used across all class objects owned by the [ahem] owner ?